# Implementing knight's tour graph and using it with different search algorithms

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, greedy, knights-tour

I want to implement knight tour and run it with different search algorithms like bfs,dfs,a* and so on.User selects a place on chessboard and then things will be done.The question is after choosing, should i create the whole graph, like all possible moves from first location then from the second one and so on, or should i take it step by step and then, according to its algorithm, create children in the first level of search and then children of children in the next levels? I hope my question was clear and sorry for my english.

Comment: you could use recursive way. and also maintain a VISITED matrix to keep tracking visited locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration, a node is popped from the queue until the destination is arrived. The repeated-moves are abandoned by using a list to record the previous history moves. To simplify the implementation, every time, the current move history array is also pushed into the queue. This is clearly a BFS (Breadth First Search) algorithm, which will guarantee the first route found is a shortest one.

---

you don't search the chessboard; search the space of placements:

Initial state: no knight is placed

Valid move: place a knight on any unoccupied tile

Goal state: all tiles are either occupied or attacked

basic algorithm (BFS of the state space):

push the initial state to the BFS queue.
while there is something in the queue:
remove one state from the queue.
for every unoccupied tile:
create a copy of the current state.
add one knight to that tile.
if the new state doesn't exist in the queue:
if the new state is a goal state, finish.
else add it to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, a feasible approach would be not to explicitly represent the game tree in terms of generating successor states, but to keep an instance of the board and implemente the search recursively by using functions for generating all possible moves, performing a move and undoing a move; by doing so, the examined part of the game tree will be implicitly represented by using the call stack while the backtracking step is implemented by undoing the last move and returning from the current recursive call.

Comment: i started to wonder: is it even possible to implement knight tour using bfs?